# jMonkeyEngine - rotate with mouse like in first-person games

Tags: java, controls, jmonkeyengine

can someone give me sample of code that will rotate my player please? I want achieve same control like in classical fps (w,a,s,d + mouse). Something with FlyByCamera but i don't know how to add it. Code is without errors. Thanks.

here are methods that are related to control

```
public class Main extends SimpleApplication
    implements ActionListener {

private Spatial platforms[];
private Spatial trees[];
private Node sceneNode;
private Node playerNode;
private Node platformNode;
private Node treeNode;
private CameraNode camNode;
private BulletAppState bullet;
private RigidBodyControl scenePhysics;
private BetterCharacterControl player;
private Vector3f walkDir = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
private Vector3f viewDir = new Vector3f(0, 0, 1);
private boolean rotateLeft = false, rotateRight = false, forward = false,
        backward = false, strafeLeft = false, strafeRight = false;
private float moveSpeed = 70;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
    AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
    app.setSettings(settings);
    settings.setTitle(“RUSHY”);
    settings.setSettingsDialogImage(“Interface/intro.png”);
    app.start();
}

public void simpleInitApp() {
    bullet = new BulletAppState();
    stateManager.attach(bullet);

    setUpKeys();

    scenePhysics = new RigidBodyControl(0f);
    sceneNode.addControl(scenePhysics);
    bullet.getPhysicsSpace().add(sceneNode);
    rootNode.attachChild(sceneNode);

    bullet.getPhysicsSpace().setGravity(new Vector3f(0, -50.0f, 0));
    bullet.getPhysicsSpace().setAccuracy(0.016f);

    playerNode = new Node(“player”);
    playerNode.setLocalTranslation(new Vector3f(0, 10, 0)); //spawn position
    rootNode.attachChild(playerNode);

    player = new BetterCharacterControl(1.5f, 7f, 30f);
    player.setJumpForce(new Vector3f(0, 1200f, 0));
    player.setGravity(new Vector3f(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f));

    playerNode.addControl(player);
    bullet.getPhysicsSpace().add(player);
}

private void setUpKeys() {
    inputManager.addMapping(“Forward”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Backward”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Rotate Left”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Rotate Right”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Strafe Right”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_E));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Strafe Left”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_Q));
    inputManager.addMapping(“Jump”,
            new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
    inputManager.addListener(this, “Rotate Left”, “Rotate Right”,
            “Strafe Right”, “Strafe Left”, “Forward”, “Backward”, “Jump”);
}

public void onAction(String binding, boolean isPressed, float tpf) {

    if (binding.equals(“Rotate Left”)) {
        rotateLeft = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Rotate Right”)) {
        rotateRight = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Strafe Left”)) {
        strafeLeft = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Strafe Right”)) {
        strafeRight = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Forward”)) {
        forward = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Backward”)) {
        backward = isPressed;
    } else if (binding.equals(“Jump”)) {
        player.jump();
    }
}

@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    camNode = new CameraNode(“CamNode”, cam);

    camNode.setControlDir(CameraControl.ControlDirection.SpatialToCamera);
    camNode.setLocalTranslation(new Vector3f(0, 6, 0));
    Quaternion quat = new Quaternion();
    quat.lookAt(Vector3f.UNIT_Z, Vector3f.UNIT_Y);
    camNode.setLocalRotation(quat);
    playerNode.attachChild(camNode);
    camNode.setEnabled(true);

    Vector3f modelForwardDir = playerNode.getWorldRotation().mult(Vector3f.UNIT_Z);
    Vector3f modelLeftDir = playerNode.getWorldRotation().mult(Vector3f.UNIT_X);

    walkDir.set(0, 0, 0);

    if (forward) {
        walkDir.addLocal(modelForwardDir.mult(moveSpeed));
    } else if (backward) {
        walkDir.addLocal(modelForwardDir.mult(moveSpeed).
                negate());
    } else if (strafeLeft) {
        walkDir.addLocal(modelLeftDir.mult(moveSpeed));
    } else if (strafeRight) {
        walkDir.addLocal(modelLeftDir.mult(moveSpeed).negate());
    }
    player.setWalkDirection(walkDir); // walk

    if (rotateLeft) {
        Quaternion rotateL = new Quaternion().
                fromAngleAxis(FastMath.PI * tpf, Vector3f.UNIT_Y);
        rotateL.multLocal(viewDir);
    } else if (rotateRight) {
        Quaternion rotateR = new Quaternion().
                fromAngleAxis(-FastMath.PI * tpf, Vector3f.UNIT_Y);
        rotateR.multLocal(viewDir);
    }
    player.setViewDirection(viewDir); // turn
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like the methods from an example:

```
private BulletAppState bulletAppState;
private Node gameLevel;
private PhysicsCharacter player;
private Vector3f walkDirection = new Vector3f();
private boolean left=false,right=false,up=false,down=false;
@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    Vector3f camDir = cam.getDirection().clone().multLocal(0.6f);
    Vector3f camLeft = cam.getLeft().clone().multLocal(0.4f);
    walkDirection.set(0,0,0);
    if(left)
        walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft);
    if(right)
        walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft.negate());
    if(up)
        walkDirection.addLocal(camDir);
    if(down)
        walkDirection.addLocal(camDir.negate());
    player.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
    cam.setLocation(player.getPhysicsLocation());
}

private void setupKeys() {
    inputManager.addMapping("Lefts", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
    inputManager.addMapping("Rights", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
    inputManager.addMapping("Ups", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
    inputManager.addMapping("Downs", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
    inputManager.addMapping("Space", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
    inputManager.addListener(this,"Lefts");
    inputManager.addListener(this,"Rights");
    inputManager.addListener(this,"Ups");
    inputManager.addListener(this,"Downs");
    inputManager.addListener(this,"Space");
}

public void onAction(String binding, boolean value, float tpf) {

    if (binding.equals("Lefts")) {
        if(value)
            left=true;
        else
            left=false;
    } else if (binding.equals("Rights")) {
        if(value)
            right=true;
        else
            right=false;
    } else if (binding.equals("Ups")) {
        if(value)
            up=true;
        else
            up=false;
    } else if (binding.equals("Downs")) {
        if(value)
            down=true;
        else
            down=false;
    } else if (binding.equals("Space")) {
        player.jump();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my player is type BetterCharacterControl and in example PhysicsCharacter. I can't use cam.setLocation(player.getPhysicsLocation());

Comment: Then you might want a `ChaseCamera`: `chaseCam = new ChaseCamera(cam, playerNode, inputManager);` . I use a ChaseCamera with a BetterCharacterControl for my jmonkey projects. (They are open source if you look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/spaceworld/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/dangerworld/ I use the BetterCharacterControl there with a ChaseCamera.